# Collisions in a HashTable Data Structure

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

I need help understanding hashtables, so correct e if I am wrong. A hashtable computes the index of the array with  a key by encripting the key. The resultant encryption is the index. Collisions are unavoidable because there are high chances of getting the same index and we can use chaining to create a linked list inside each index of the array. The runtime of a hashtable is  o(1)

Comment: It _hashes the key_ is better than saying _encrypting the key_  as it is usually a  lossy operation and secrecy is not the goal.  "The runtime of a hashtable is o(1)" is hoped for, yet not certain.  I suggest re-writing this post's 3 questions into one to make it less broad.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, a hash table has O(1) lookup and O(n) storage space.
A hashing function is used to compute the index for where we store the element in a hash table. When a collision occurs we chain them.

Comment: "a hash table has O(1) lookup and O(n) storage space." --> Maybe `O(1)`,  and maybe `O(n)` storage space.  A quality HT will approach `O(1)` lookup  and `O(n)` storage space, but its more like `O(1)`-ish and  `O(n + ht_size)` storage space.  Many factors.

Comment: Very true your answer is more precise.